# Start only foreground service on boot but not the main activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to auto-start a foreground service (without starting the main activity) after boot.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver android:name=".MyBootCompletedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

**Broadcast receiver:**

```
public class MyBootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent intentService = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intentService);
        }
    }
}
```

On **Android 8.1.0, API 27 emulator**, this works as expected and the main activity is not shown on boot but only the notification.

> On **Android 5.1.1, API 22 emulator**, the notification shows up correctly, however even the app (MainActivity) starts.

How do I make that only the service, but not the app starts after boot on all API levels?

Comment: Can you share MainActivity xml part in AndroidManifest? And by app starts you mean the mainactivity also launches(showsup) right with the service?

Comment: @udit7395 xml updated. Yes, the mainactivity launches after boot completes.

Comment: This is strange behavior. I have apps that use BOOT_COMPLETED and work as expected. Can you test on another API maybe 23 or 24 perhaps. Also, this might sound stupid but can you check from where all is mainactivity being launched perhaps from another receiver(since all BroadcastReceiver do work below API 27).

Comment: Tested it on Android 7.0, API 24 and the activity is getting launched even in this emulator. The only reference to MainActivity class is inside the Service which is a (pending)intent to launch MainActivity when the notification is clicked.

Comment: Yeah, this shouldn't happen... suggest dumping the return value from `MainActivity.getIntent()` in `onCreate()`, and using that to try to infer the origin of the `Intent`.

Comment: Implementation simple and effective. It worked for me.